# Help with ASP.Net C# chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

Im using the following code to display a column chart

```
Chart1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
Chart1.BackSecondaryColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
Chart1.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalRight;

Chart1.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
Chart1.BorderlineColor = Color.Gray;
Chart1.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;

// format the chart area
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Wheat;
// add and format the title
Chart1.Titles.Add("TOTAL GP Against TARGET  ");
Chart1.Titles[0].Font = new Font("Utopia", 16);

Chart1.Series.Add(new Series("total")
  {
  ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
  });

Chart1.Series.Add(new Series("perc")
  {
   ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
   });

 Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

 // clear the chart series and bind to the table
 DataView dataView = new DataView(dt);

 Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(dataView, "NAME", dataView, "total");
 Chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(dataView, "NAME", dataView, "perc");
```

this works fine, however i want to create a another chart which just display the data from on the rows, and im doing something like

```
Chart2.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(dataView.RowFilter = "NAME = 'John' ", "NAME", dataView, "perc");
```

but it doesn't seem to work, can any one suggest how I may be able to do this?

Comment: Probably when you `.DataBindXY()` again you clear the previous data. btw. why do you assign a value in first argument: `dataView.RowFilter = "NAME =John"` ?? what are you trying to achieve ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataView dataView = new DataView(dt);
dataView.RowFilter = "NAME = 'John'";

Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(dataView, "NAME", dataView, "perc");
```

Comment: i get an error of X values cannot be data bound to the string object.
Parameter name: xValue